# Seo for Single Page Application

Tags: javascript, seo, single-page-application, multilingual

I want to build SPA application based on knockout.js that will be hosted on IIS. My project consists of js/html only and i try to avoid any server-side processing. That cause several questions:

**1.** My application should support several languages. Can i use URL like *www.example.com/#!en/...* , is it popular practise? Will Google index my site well?

**2.** I know that main way to make my SPA crawlable is 'snapshots'. What is your's favorit tool to create snapshots on crawler's demand?

Answer (score 0):

The URL should not determine the locale used to render your application. There is a header in HTTP (`Accept-Language`) that can be used for your first guess, but you should enable the user to override this.

The URL is the location of a resource. If I have a page `www.example.com/foo.html` then it can be argued that that is the same resource regardless of language used to represent it.